# Apache-2.4 as a reverse proxy for NGINX - Log Real IP

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I configured apache-2.4 on windows as a reverse-proxy for my internal nginx server on linux (I know! But don't ask me why!!). Almost everything works great, except:

I believe I have configured nginx to log the real ip using this header: `X-Real-IP`. [Reference](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html). Now in my reverse-proxy what do I do to set this header to the IP address of the client so that it can be logged. Note that SSL is a must on apache-2.4. Currently my http-vhosts.conf has this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl on
    RequestHeader set X-URL-SCHEME https
    ServerName www.external.gateway:443
    ServerAlias external.gateway:443 
    ErrorLog "C:/Apache24/logs/gateway-error.log" 
    CustomLog "C:/Apache24/logs/gateway-access.log" common
    # ServerAdmin admin@gateway.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile C:/Apache24/ssl/external.gateway.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile C:/Apache24/ssl/external.gateway.key
    <Location />
       SSLRequireSSL
    </Location>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://internal.nginx:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://internal.nginx:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

PS: I can probably use `X-Forwarded-For` in nginx, but I need to know what to do to set that header in apache httpd.conf. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're using mod_proxy_http then that is already adding X-Forwarded-For headers to requests to the backend server. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will try as you suggested and post an update when I get a chance.

Comment: @wurtel, I just had to enable mod_proxy_http, configure nginx to use that header... and viola, it works like a charm! If you post an answer I will accept it or I will wait a little and post an answer myself for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to [wurtel](https://serverfault.com/users/241548/wurtel)

- Enable `mod_proxy_http` in apache httpd (reverse-proxy) in the httpd.conf, like so:

  LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
  LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
- Use `X-Forwarded-For` to log the IP in nginx (upstream) as mentioned [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html)